# Mongo / Mongoose, relationship storage

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm really new at Mongo / Mongoose and I'm encountering that in my models I may new a few models with relationships (One to One, One to Many, Many to Many). I've researched some good examples on how to create relationships on Mongoose like the one below:

[Understanding Relationships & Foreign Keys in Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912127/understanding-relationships-foreign-keys-in-mongoose)

However, according to Mongo Docs, there are 2 ways to store relationships: within the same collection or by document reference.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/

I have 3 questions about this topic.

1- When should I use approach or another? Is this based on the requirements of my business data and on how would I perform searches? 
2- Is it good practice to combine both types of data storages?
3- How can I configure Mongoose to store the relationship data within the Same collection or as a Document Reference?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use relations, you should use a relational database like MySQL, if you don't like SQL then you can use a database like RethinkDB, Relations in Mongo are wonky. With that said, I will try to answer your question to the best of my knowledge.

1 - When should I use approach or another?

IMO, you should always keep data separate if it can be. For example, in a blog, you want to keep comments and posts in their own collections, and refer the Posts as a hasMany relation to the comments collection. Yes, you can just add comments to the post document, but let's say you want to add a way for your users to be able to see their comments, then you'd have to build a query to look at each comment of each post and that's just bad.

2 - Is it good practice to combine both types of data storages?

This question seems to be the same as the first one

3 - How can I configure Mongoose to store the relationship data within the Same collection or as a Document Reference?

Let's clear something first, Mongo stores documents inside collections.
To have the relation inside the document you would just add a property to that document where it will be populated. Blog example:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const postSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    date: String,
    author: String,
    text: String,
    comments: Array
})
export default mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);
```

Now, this might seem like the simpler, better way to do it if your application will be statically the same and you don't care about scalability. What I recommend you do is keep your concerns separate.

Based on that example schema, you can say that `author` and `comments` could, and should, be their own collections.

**Authors** (has many posts, has many comments)

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const authorSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    posts: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Post'
    }],
    comments: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Comment'
    }]
})
export default mongoose.model('Author', authorSchema);
```

**Comments** (belongs to author, has one post)

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const commentSchema = new Schema({
    author: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId
        ref: 'Author'
    },
    post:{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Post'
    }
})
export default mongoose.model('Comment', commentSchema);
```

**Posts** (belongs to author, has many comments)

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const postsSchema = new Schema({
    author: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId
        ref: 'Author'
    },
    title: String,
    date: String,
    text: String,
    comments: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Comment'
    }]
})
export default mongoose.model('Post', postsSchema);
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for your great answer @Baruch, it makes a lot of sense now. I'm  from a SQL world and it was a bit confusing to understand relationships on a 'non relational' schema. Thanks a lot

Comment: Ohh btw @Baruch ... I found this really helpful article about relationships, in case it is useful for you http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87200945828/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1

Comment: @DavidEspino Thanks for sharing. I haven't used Mongo in like 6 months. I tried it out, found RethinkDB, fell in love. But at the moment, my work requires me me use MySQL which I don't mind.

Comment: A gentle response to "keeping things separate", Mongo white papers (and there are soooo many on the official site I'd suggest all new mongo devs dedicate a couple evenings to just reading around) encourage sub-collections for the majority of what one would normally express as relations. There are certainly occasions where you categorically shouldn't put data into sub collections, but they're relatively infrequent by contrast to RDBMSs.  
Use Mongo like an RDBMS and it will perform like an RDBMS; ie, ok but not at its best. Mongo works on the assumption that disk space is no longer a premium.

Comment: @JonathanEdwards Thanks for your input, but this is from 1 year ago and I don't use MongoDB anymore so I wouldn't know what has changed in that time. I do agree that sub-collections (or nested collections) is the best way to go in order to maximize speed. The whole idea of NoSQL is to have faster response times when doing get requests.